# Draw large DrawingVisual in Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, winforms

**Background**

I have a large report in my WinForms application that is generated into a WPF `DrawingVisual`. I want to display the report in a separate resizable window that enables the users to scroll up/down as they read it. In this case the report doesn't have any page breaks and consist of one large page.

**First attempt:**

Use a customized `DocumentViewer` to display the report.

Added the `DrawingVisual` into a `FixedDocument` with a custom height, added the FixedDocument into a `FixedDocumentSequence` and finally passed the document sequence into the print preview window (that uses a custom DocumentViewer).

```
var previewWindow = new ReportPrintPreview(docSeq);
previewWindow.Show();
```

Classes:

```
public class ReportPrintPreview : Window
{
   private readonly DocumentViewer docViewer;

   public ReportPrintPreview(IDocumentPaginatorSource doc)
   {
      docViewer = new CustomDocumentViewer();
      docViewer.Document = doc;
   }

   protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnInitialized(e);
      AddChild(docViewer);
   }
}

public class CustomDocumentViewer : DocumentViewer
{
   public CustomDocumentViewer()
   {
      ShowPageBorders = false;
   }

   protected override void OnPrintCommand()
   {
   }
}
```

This works and gives good performance for large reports, but I find the customization possibilities of the `DocumentViewer` limiting. Want to add combo boxes in the toolbar and control the zoom of the report when the window is resized for example.

**Second attempt:**

Use a regular Windows Forms form and draw the `DrawingVisual` using a `ElementHost`. The element host is placed inside a panel to enable scrolling.

```
var form = new ReportViewer(visual, pSize);
form.ShowDialog();
```

Classes:

```
public partial class ReportViewer : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{

   public ReportViewer(DrawingVisual visual, Size size)
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      var wpfPanel = new WpfDrawingUserControl(visual);
      elementHost1.Width = size.Width;
      elementHost1.Height = size.Height;
      elementHost1.Child = wpfPanel;
   }
}

public class WpfDrawingUserControl : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
{
   public WpfDrawingUserControl(DrawingVisual visual)
   {
      var image = new Image();
      image.Source = new DrawingImage(visual.Drawing);
      Content = image;
   }
}
```

I create a UserControl that contains an image that is created from the `DrawingGroup` of the `DrawingVisual`.

This kind of works, but the performance when scrolling is bad. And it even crashes when the report is large enough.

**Solution?**

How can I do more effective drawing of the `DrawingVisual` in the form? I guess the whole `DrawingVisual` will be painted in the UserControl even when just a part of the report is showing in the scroll enabled panel.

Alternatively, how can I customize the `DocumentViewer` or create my own WPF control to display the `DrawingVisual`.

Comment: You could derive your own class from DocumentViewerBase and make your own viewer just the way you want it.  That's not entirely untrivial, DocumentViewer adds a fair amount of plumbing.  Use the Reference Source or a decompiler to get a head-start.

Comment: Thanks, I was actually in the process of dotPeeking DocumentViewer. Would prefer to write the viewer in winforms (not as experienced in WPF), but think I'll have to go that path.